# "map is not a function" with redux-orm 0.9.0

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-orm

I'm creating a simple example to learn the `redux-orm` library. I've set up my reducer as below and everything seems to work great.

```
const orm = new ORM();
orm.register(Profile, User);
export function reducer(state, {type, payload}) {
  const session = orm.session(state || orm.getEmptyState());
  switch(type) {
    case 'CREATE_USER':
      session.User.create(payload)
      break;

    case 'CREATE_PROFILE':
      session.Profile.create(payload)
      break;
  }
  return session.state;
}
```

I'm following the example to create a simple selector, that gets the entire list of users in the DB:

```
export const getUsers = createSelector(orm, session => {
  return session.User.map(user => {
    return user.ref
  });
});
```

However, upon using the selector, Chrome gives me an error:
`ERROR TypeError: session.User.map is not a function`

Am I missing something? Or is this a bug with the library?

Comment: Like @VipinKumar said, `.map()` function works on `Array`s. Try this code in your console for proof: `[1,2,3].map(function (number) { console.log(number); });`. Could you show us the output of `console.log(session.User)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either `toModelArray` or `toRefArray`. The equivalent code to what you seem to be going for in your example (getting the refs for each `User`) would be:

```
return session.User.all().toRefArray()
```

If you need to do further processing, like getting relations or refining to only a subset of properties, use `toModelArray` and `map` through it as you would a normal array.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Apparently the library's documentation is out-of-date (as of 12/18/2017). 

Also, another issue that was likely causing my problem is that I was passing the root app `state` to the selector I created rather than passing `state.entities` (where the redux-orm DB is mounted).